# While loop doesn't perfom second iteration

Tags: python, opencv, pytorch

my code is:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
frame_width = int(cap.get(3))
frame_height = int(cap.get(4))

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True: 
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        time.sleep(0.001)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        print("you suck")
        break 

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The problem is it doesn't do the second iteration, it just performs the first one and then gets stuck. interesting is that when I delete import:
`from model.return_model import return_model, process_frames` which basically imports pytorch model, it works perfectly. I am trying to debug it, but can't find any solution

Comment: Have you used a debugger to see where the script "gets stuck"?

Comment: yes, it gets stuck on: `cv2.imshow('frame',frame)` line

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal but frame isn't None, when i save the frame on disk i see good image

Comment: And it's not opening a window with an image, I assume? What are you running your code on?

Comment: @B Remmelzwaal i feel like, pytorch model might have something to do with it, because when i stop importing it, issue resolves

Comment: @B Remmelzwaal I am using Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

Comment: remove the `time.sleep`. that's an error for users to call in any loop that processes GUI events. -- `assert cap.isOpened()` in front of the loop.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz same, result, code looks like this:
```
assert cap.isOpened()
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        print("you suck")
        break 

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Are you using any additional threads? Can you show your full code, including that dmn import? What exactly is process_frames and return_model?

Comment: @Micka no i am not using threads, maybe  pytorch or opencv be using it

Answer (score -1):

Guys I resolved the issue. I used `sudo` to run the script, and it worked

Comment: No, answers should not be edited into the question. They should be posted here in the answer section, but note that this answer would benefit from more details. I'm not an expert here, but `sudo` seems like a strange solution.